# ClickHouse - Search multiple array columns and retrieve filtered based on array index position

Tags: sql, arrays, clickhouse

I have clickhouse table below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db.logs
( `timestamp` DateTime CODEC(Delta(4),
 ZSTD(1)),
    `message` String,    
    `source_type` LowCardinality(String),
    `labels_key` Array(String),
    `labels_value` Array(String),
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY timestamp
PRIMARY KEY (timestamp)
ORDER BY
(timestamp)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

```sql
INSERT into db.logs(message, source_type, labels_key, labels_value) values ('red car', 'government', ['color', 'make', 'year', 'type', 'interior'], ['red', 'audi', '2021', 'sedan', 'black']);
INSERT into db.logs(message, source_type, labels_key, labels_value) values ('red car', 'private', ['color', 'make', 'year', 'type', 'interior'], ['red', 'toyota', '2020', 'crossover', 'black']);
INSERT into db.logs(message, source_type, labels_key, labels_value) values ('big truck', 'delivery', ['color', 'make', 'year', 'type', 'interior'], ['white', 'dodge', '2023', 'pickup', 'red']);
INSERT into db..logs(message, source_type, labels_key, labels_value) values ('small car', 'private', ['color', 'make', 'year', 'type', 'interior'], ['yellow', 'bmw', '2020', 'hatchback', 'yellow']);
```

```
array columns:
['color','make','year','type', 'interior']  ['red','toyota','2020','crossover', 'black']
['color','make','year','type', 'interior']  ['white','dodge','2023','pickup', 'black']
['color','make','year','type', 'interior']  ['red','audi','2021','sedan', 'red']
['color','make','year','type', 'interior']  ['yellow','bmw','2020','hatchback', 'yellow']
```

I want to select data based on labels_key index, for example `"where (labels_key = 'color' and labels_value = 'red') AND (labels_key = 'make' and labels_value = 'audi') AND (labels_key = 'year' and labels_value = '2021')"`

Table has approx. 1000 inserts/sec and timestamp can't be used, I used the query below but it works only for single search criteria:

```sql
SELECT
    timestamp,
    message,
    key,
    value,
    labels_key,
    labels_value
FROM
    db.logs
    ARRAY
JOIN labels_key AS key,
    labels_value AS value
WHERE
    toYYYYMMDD(timestamp) = '20230427'
    AND (key = 'color' AND value = 'red' )
order by
    timestamp desc ,
    message
LIMIT 100;
```

Labels can increase over time and search criteria might have more conditions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the elements in arrays is always the same as in the example, then you can choose the needed position of elements for filtering:

```
SELECT timestamp, message, labels_key[1] as key, labels_value[1] as value 
FROM db.logs 
WHERE
labels_key[1]='color' and labels_value[1]='red'
LIMIT 100;
```

Or you can do this if your array doesn't have the same structure:

```
SELECT timestamp, message, labels_key[indexOf(labels_key, 'color')] as key, labels_value[indexOf(labels_key, 'color')] as value
FROM db.logs 
WHERE has(labels_key, 'color')
and labels_value[indexOf(labels_key, 'color')]='red'
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this query and it seems to do the job, still something better would nice:

```sql
select
    timestamp, message , labels_key as keys , labels_value, indexOf(keys, 'color') as key_index1, indexOf(keys, 'model') as key_index2
from
    db.logs
WHERE arrayElement(labels_value, key_index1) = 'blue' and arrayElement(labels_value, key_index2) = 'accord';
```